# Grade E on Make fewer HTTP requests in YSlow for my magento website

Tags: apache, http, magento

Grade E on Make fewer HTTP requests

This page has 3 external stylesheets. Try combining them into one.
This page has 19 external background images. Try combining them with CSS sprites.

What should i do to improve it to Grade A. 
Is there anything i should in .htaccess file or anywhere else to improve this.
I have already done a lot of things and I got the score 89 but i want to improve it to Grade A.I am using apache server.
How would i do this.Please suggest someone.

Thanks

Comment: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/mod

Comment: Deleted accepted answer link: https://web.archive.org/web/20140327173649/http://www.gxjansen.com/101-ways-to-speed-up-your-magento-e-commerce-website/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really simple way to fix your external stylesheet problem: open up your Magento admin, go to System>Configuration>Advanced>Developer and under CSS Settings set "Merge CSS Files" to Yes.

To resolve the second issue, creating a CSS sprite sheet is a good idea (though it can be a bit of a time sink unless you did it from the start). Loading your theme graphics independently causes your response time to take a pretty big hit, so the general idea is to have your site icons and background images load in a single file, then use some CSS trickery to only show them as you need them. This article on Smashing Magazine should get you started with CSS sprites: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/11/css-sprites-revisited/

As for overall speed optimisation, there are numerous (extensive) blog posts on this subject, just have a search for them. Make sure you know what you're doing before making changes to your server configuration, or else a slow response will be the least of your troubles!

Comment: Just to add, when building sprites, I personally like to keep the image itself in the css/images folder (as well as any other images loaded via CSS). This way it keeps your regular images and your css images separate, and you can always just use url(images/sprite.png) in your CSS instead of potentially having to use an absolute url to the file. You can't do everything in a sprite if you need to keep compatibility with IE < 9 (background-size not supported) but it certainly helps a lot.